# Unable to assign value '<unknown>' to attribute 'XXX'

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy the project to the App Engine but I'm getting the following error if I use the 'ü' character as a value inside the app.yaml. I don't want to HTML/URL encode the value. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [app.yaml]
Unable to assign value '<unknown>' to attribute 'XXX':
Value u'\xfc' for XXX could not be converted to type str.
```

app.yaml file:

```
runtime: php72
env: standard

env_variables: 
  XXX: "ü"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a ticket to Google Support and I got the following response.

> Upon investigating this issue, I found that the only available
>   workaround is to load an ASCII representation of the non-ASCII
>   characters and then transform within the app's logic.
>
> Additionally, I found that a Feature Request already exist for this
>   issue, but currently there is not an ETA for its implementation or
>   guaranty that it will be done.